# Changing NLog target from file to Stackify

Tags: .net, nlog

I want to have my application logs on Stackify as well as text files. So I add a target to nlog in web config as follows:

```
<extensions>
  <add assembly="StackifyLib.nLog"/>
</extensions>
<targets>
  <target name="stackify" type="StackifyTarget" globalContextKeys="examplekey1,key2" 
        mappedContextKeys="" callContextKeys="" logMethodNames="true" />
</targets>
<rules>
  <logger name="*" writeTo="stackify" minlevel="Debug" />
</rules>
```

When I do this the log files are not updated anymore, i.e. nothing is appended to the text files. Any idea why this affects other targets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is Matt from Stackify.

You need to set your NLog config to have 2 targets and 2 rules as shown here. It should look about like this:

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">    
  <extensions>
    <add assembly="StackifyLib.NLog"/>
  </extensions>
  <targets>
    <target name="stackify" type="StackifyTarget" logMethodNames="true" logAllParams="true" />
    <target xsi:type="File" name="default" fileName="stackifynlog.log" />
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" writeTo="stackify" minlevel="Debug" />
    <logger name="*" writeTo="default" minlevel="Debug" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Also, here is a link to our docs and GitHub for more info.

http://support.stackify.com/hc/en-us/articles/205419505-Errors-and-Logs-With-NLog

https://github.com/stackify/stackify-api-dotnet#nlog-2012---v31

Thanks!